# Unity3D бесконечная платформа!

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

как реализовать плоскую бесконечную платформу. К примеру, при передвижении персонажа будут удаляться платформы, которые остались позади, и создаваться следующие.С передвижением в другие стороны, должно тоже работать[image: Игрок спавнится в середине]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_vtK-L1L7Y&t=1s
И лучше не создавать заново каждый раз, а сделать пул участков дороги и перемещать оттуда.

Answer (score 2):

Поделите платформу на несколько частей. Сделайте триггер. И когда кусок платформы касается триггера, переместите его на позицию за камерой из, которой она будет появляться. И двигайте куски в сторону против направления двежения игрока.
(Самого игрока двигать не надо)

Comment: А если игрок будет бежать прямо, то как будут спавниться части по бокам?